# Why paste command doesn't work for Concatenating two files column wise when the characters are more than 511?

Tags: text-processing, solaris, csv, paste

I am using a paste command to concatenate two **.csv** files column wise.
These both files are huge file and when I run the **paste** command as below where comma(,) is the delimiter:

```
paste -d',' file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

The command fails giving output

```
paste: line too long
```

However, I searched the same over internet and in paste command's manual also. I found the below diagnostics.

```
"line too long"         Output lines are restricted  to  511
                         characters.
```

Is there any alternate way to obtain the result, then?

I am using below version of bash:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this command

```
nawk '{if ((getline a < "-") > 0) $0 = $0 "," a; print}' file1.csv < file2.csv > file3.csv
```

this command will browse your `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` line by line and save the line from the `file1.csv` in `$0` (for nawk `$0` match the hole line, `$1` the first column, `$2` the second...) and save the line from `file2.csv` in the variable `a`. After that it will print `$0` (the line from file1), then "," then `a` (the line from file2) in the `file3.csv`

Comment: OP needs a `,` separator between lines from the two files

Comment: Thanks @Dababi The files get concatenated within no time but without delimiter. I want to put ',' comma while concatenating the files.
Also can you explain the command line, what is the use of '-', $0 = $0, a.

Comment: I update the command, it will  work as expected. Try it and give me the result

Comment: @Dababi thanks the solution and its explanation. It is completely working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the file to a new filehandle and read from it while reading from input:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec 3< file1
while read -r two ; do
    read -r -u3 one
    echo "$one,$two"
done < file2
```

Comment: you mind explaining what this will do , Please.

Comment: It redirects file1 to filehandle 3, then reads file2 line by line, reading one line from fh 3 at the same time, and outputting both values read from the files.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the tools provided by Solaris are inferior to GNU tools. You should install them, if possible. If not, there might be a better `paste` in `xpg4`.